# On a dual monitor setup, how can I set which lone monitor the ALT-TAB interface appears?

Tags: multiple-monitors

On a dual monitor setup, how can I set which monitor the ALT-TAB (or ALT+`) interfaces appear?

Right now, it's flying all over the place, possibly based on on which app is focused? I'm not sure. In any case this is not useful to me. I spend 80% of my time staring at the monitor in front of me, and sometimes I turn my head to the left to look at logs, or whatever.

When I press ALT-TAB or ALT+`, I want the interface to appear, 100% of the time, on the monitor in front of me.

Geforce GT 430, NVIDIA binary drivers, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Help?

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, it seems to display on the monitor that has the mouse cursor in it.